# Meaning of "Episodes-titles" of Sacred Games?

Tags: title, sacred-games

How do the episode titles for *Sacred Games* (the first Netflix original series in India) relate to the series?

1. Ashwathama
2. Halahala
3. Atapi Vatapi
4. Brahmahatya
5. Sarama
6. Pretakalpa
7. Rudra
8. Yayati

Comment: I haven't seen this series, but from what I can gather from the wikipedia page, these words, such as the warrior Ashwathama seem to want the give the crime/gangster series an allegorical element and/or themes on myth/spirituality.

Comment: i appreciate your efforts but there is a specific reason for each of the name of title. Trying to get that information.

Comment: I understand. and if I watched it, I might of been able to better apply them better and make a real answer, but each title relates to a mythological story. Halahala for instance, relates to poison or toxin from some myth deriving from the sea - again an allegorical quality.

Comment: Actually I may have found an article that breaks the Hindu mythology down...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The name of each title refers to **Hindu Mythology**, such as [Ashwatthama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashwatthama) being the name of legendary cursed immortal warrior.

Because the series is a gangster crime drama and not a straight on Hindu fantasy, the concept is then that these ideas are **religiously [allegorical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory) in nature** being a references to apply as a theme or parable, by showing them in the real world, which could also make the series a slight **post modern** retelling.

The following [article](https://www.hindustantimes.com/tv/fascinated-by-sacred-games-use-of-hindu-mythology-episode-titles-decoded/story-2Vs0K3H00qml1fvS1UxKRJ.html) breaks down some of it.

> **Aswatthama** was cursed with immortality after Kurukshetra war,” the
>   post says, but “Gaitonde commits suicide but his story remains alive.”
>   In the show, Nawazuddin Siddiqui’s gangster character, Ganesh
>   Gaitonde, dies at the end of episode 1, but narrates the story of his
>   rise to power (juxtaposed with the turbulent history of communalism in
>   modern India) in the remaining episodes.
>
> “**Halahala** is a lethal poison from Samudra Manthan. Lord Shiva consumed
>   it to protect the universe.” The show’s protagonist, Sartaj Singh,
>   played by Saif Ali Khan, “starts to investigate Gaitonde’s warning and
>   unravels an international espionage.” This has also been interpreted
>   as an international terror plot.
>
> **“Aatapi and Vatapi** were two demons who used to trick travellers with
>   hospitality and kill them. Religions welcome people and then hinges on
>   their souls.” An alternate theory offered is that Atapi and Vatapi are
>   represented in the show by two aides of Gaitonde’s - “Bunty and Bada
>   Badriya are Atapi Vatapi. Bunty is the one who convinced Gaitonde to
>   join Bhonsle and Bada Badriya betrayed him with Isa. Gaitonde is the
>   Rahgeer here.”
>
> **“Brahmahatya**,” the Redditor says, “means killing of a Brahmin. It is a
>   hideous crime in Hinduism. “Gaitonde ignores his own Brahmin self and
>   agrees to poach Muslims votes for Hindu politician Bhosale.” In the
>   show, Gaitonde’s inner Hindu is birthed after a personal betrayal. The
>   book also mentions that for some time during the ‘90s, Gaitonde
>   projects himself as a Hindu don, taking advantage of the growing anger
>   directed towards Muslims.
>
> **“Sarama** means dog. In a long run, everyone is a dog with a leash.”
>   This could be a reference to Sartaj, who is shackled even as he tries
>   to do the right thing. It is in this episode that he finally gives in
>   and “lies in his confession for Bengali Bura case.
>   “Pretakalpa is the rites to perform the cremation of a Hindu.” It is
>   in this episode that Sartaj’s constable and friend Katekar is killed.
>   Sartaj cremates Katekar and kills his murderer, metaphorically killing
>   his older self. This episode is also a major turning point in his
>   character.
>
> “**Rudra** is the personification of terror in Hinduism.” It is in this
>   episode that Gaitonde’s lover, “Subhadra is killed,” and he goes on a
>   rampage against Muslims.
>
> Finally, **“Yayati** was cursed with premature old age. He asked his son
>   Puru to swap their ages.” It is in this episode that Gaitonde reveals
>   the identity of his third father, Guru Ji. And it is also in this
>   episode that Gaitonde pledges his allegiance to Guru Ji’s cause.
>
> What exactly his cause is remains to be seen and will be explored when
>   (not if) the show returns with more episodes. The character is played
>   by Pankaj Tripathi in the show, who co-director Anurag Kashyap
>   revealed in an interview to Hindustan Times, evolves into a major
>   player towards the end of the story.